# Update VBA macros across multiple Excel files

Tags: macros, vba

I have created a few VBA Macros and I need to use the same macros in different files.

So say I have a macro "X" and I have files "A", "B" and "C" that use the same macro "X". Currently whenever I adjust the macro, I need to go in each file and update the macro manually.

I was wondering if there's way I can have the Excel files pull the most recent macro from a repository / folder or anywhere where I can keep the most recent code and not have to go into each and every file to update it?

Comment: Where are the workbooks because this sounds like a job for your personal macro workbook - personal.xlsb

Comment: They are all in Dropbox and in the same folder. Multiple users use ti and have to be able to run the macros. Would I need to install/update the personal macro workbook - personal.xlsb in all computers?

Comment: If multiple users run the macros then the personal won't work - that's only local.